# Menu in laravel 5 Multiple levels?

Tags: php, laravel-5

**Model:**

```
class Menu extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'menus';

    public function sub_menu(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Menu', 'parent_id');
    }

}
```

**Controller:**

```
class MenuController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $menus = Menu::where('parent_id', 0)->get();
        return view('admin.menus.index',compact('menus'));
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<ul>
    @foreach($menus as $menu)
    <li>{{ $menu->title }}
    @if($menu->sub_menu->count() > 0)
       <ul>
       @foreach($menu->sub_menu as $sub)
           <li{{ $sub->title }}</li>
       @endforeach
       </ul>
   @endif
   </li>
   @endforeach
</ul>
```

**Table Structure:**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        id          |          title            |      parent_id
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        1           |          Home             |          0
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        2           |        Product1           |          0
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        3           |       Product1.1          |          2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        4           |       Product1.1.1        |          3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        5           |       Product1.1.2        |          3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It's show only 2 levels but I need multiple levels, please help!

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: @AmitGupta.op is aking if the menus are multi level then he need to display menu in loop but he is using foreach loop it will end up with two step menu.i hope he need to use while loop

Comment: @AmitGupta, It's show only 2 levels but I need Multiple levels. please help!

Comment: Didn't get you. Can you show in your question what you have got and what you need?

Comment: @AmitGupta Ok I've just edited my question already. thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can try it using recursion as:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($menus as $menu)
        <li>
            {{ $menu->title }}
            @if($menu->sub_menu->count())
                {!! view('admin.menus.index', ['menus' => $menu->sub_menu]) !!}
            @endif
     </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

It will work when your view has only the above content otherwise, you have create new partial and call it recursively.

*Just be careful you may end in an infinite loop using recursion.*

Comment: No, it doesn't work for multiple levels but for 1 level work fine. thank you so much but Now I solved it already by create function recursive in model. thanks!

Comment: You can check this [repo](https://github.com/atayahmet/laravel-nestable) also. Looks it will help you.